# Unable to read USB to serial input in ubuntu 18.04 for various serial sensors

Tags: linux, serial-port, usb, iot, ubuntu-18.04

I am using Prolific 2303 serial usb to connect to various sensors and serial terms like (monoterm,coolterm) to monitor the serial output in ubuntu 18.04 but something seems to go wrong as i am not able to see the output date even when the driver and the usb seems to work fine. 
I have already updated the access permissions for the usb port and also launching the serialTerminal with root permissions.
Output For `lsusb` is as follows :

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 8087:0ab6 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 214b:7250  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and 
for `dmesg | grep tty` is as follows :

```
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[    6.724357] 8086228A:00: ttyS4 at MMIO 0x91420000 (irq = 39, base_baud = 2764800) is a 16550A
[    6.742117] 8086228A:01: ttyS5 at MMIO 0x9141e000 (irq = 40, base_baud = 2764800) is a 16550A
[    7.100607] usb 1-3: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[    8.088988] cdc_acm 1-4:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```

the serial port connects successfully but does not returns any output,I know am missing something but unable to figure out.
As Requested in the comments sharing the minimal python code to read data.

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')
print(ser.readline())
```

Comment: I have updated the question with python code to read, however i believe you missed that i have mentioned that i am using serial terminal tools like coolterm etc to monitor values and they do not require code.

Comment: If all you want to do is install drivers and configure the device, then it is probably a question for [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The drivers are installed to and also i shall be more than glad to have a python solution to overcome these issues.

Comment: What are you connecting to the serial port? What about its settings? (Baudrate, parity, stopbits...) Have you tried connecting with minicom or picocom to see if you have the right settings and something is getting through to your port? For some sensors you might need to query them first before you see a reaction

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been abandoned without further investigation or followup by the asker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by setting limit to the read bits by the sensor, as the problem was that the sensor wasn't sending the EOL char, so readline got into infinite read and the program never returned values. So I used chunks of bytes to read data.